# Зачем точка с запятой в конце запроса для защиты от sql иньекций?

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

Один знакомый сказал, что в конце запроса sql при работе (в php в моем) случае нужно ставить точку с запятой для защиты от sql иньекций.

Безусловно самый правильный способ использовать prepare-функционал  для параметров запроса. Но...

Подскажите в каком случае это может помочь, если бы я подставлял параметры прямо в строку? не могу понять.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще-то точка запятая появилась как альтернатива "go". ";" от sql инъекций не понятно как спасет. пример.
'select * from table where id = ' + @someinput + ';'

@someinput = '1; drop table'

Comment: Именно, не спасает от слова совсем, если не фильтровать данные.